# Angular - How to combine multiple "valueChanges" observables into one

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

How can I combine the following subscriptions into one?

```
    this.form.get("type").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.calcFinalTransports();
    })
    this.form.get("departure").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.calcFinalTransports();
    })
    this.form.get("destination").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.calcFinalTransports();
    })
    this.form.get("stations").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.calcFinalTransports();
    })
```

Comment: Subscribe to `this.form.valueChanges`? Or do you mean something more like an `Observable.merge`? It's not clear.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com answer is exactly what i need? Why do you downvote? I was very clear

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a few choices depending on what output you expect. You may want to read this article:

- [Learn to combine RxJs sequences with super intuitive interactive diagrams](https://indepth.dev/posts/1114/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams)

If you just want to get notified whenever any of the value changes use `merge`:

```
import {merge} from "rxjs/observable/merge";

merge(
    this.form.get("type").valueChanges,
    this.form.get("departure").valueChanges,
    this.form.get("destination").valueChanges
    this.form.get("stations").valueChanges
).subscribe(() => this.calcFinalTransports());
```

Comment: This seems to throw an error in VSCode saying `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<any>>'.`.  Has this changed in RxJS5?

Comment: @mtpultz, I don't know, I suggest you ask another quetsion

Comment: Seems to work if I merge onto an initial observable using a pipe: `first$.pipe(merge(second$, third$,...).subscribe(...);`

Comment: The link provided @MaxKoretskyi is no longer valid.  This [one](https://indepth.dev/posts/1114/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams) seems to be the right one.

Answer (score 2):

If want to use single Data observable pattern and combine multiple observables into one observable, then *combineLatest*  may come as useful.

PesudoCode

```
userNameAndEmail$=this.userNameAndEmail().pipe(startsWith(null));
userAddressDetail$=this.userAddressDetails().pipe(startsWith(null));
userMiscDetails$=this.userMiscDtls();


completeUserData$=combineLatest([userNameAndEmail$,userAddressDetail$,userMiscDetails$])
.pipe(map(([userNameAndEmail,userAddressDetail,userMiscDetails])=>{  
 return {userNameAndEmail,userAddressDetail,userMiscDetails};  } ));
```

However, there are certain conditions.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer on this related question shows to get the `combineLatest` to emit when not all of the added observables have emitted a value yet. This works great when your form controls are initialized with values of `undefined`.

[RxJS combineLatest without waiting for source observables to emit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039425/rxjs-combinelatest-without-waiting-for-source-observables-to-emit)

```
combineLatest([
  source1$.pipe(startWith(undefined)),
  source2$.pipe(startWith(undefined)),
])
```