# RxJS combineLatest without waiting for source observables to emit?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two source observables from where I need to calc some data as soon as one source observable emits. I'm trying to use the `combineAll()` operator but it only emits a value when each of the source observables emits for the first time.

Is there any operator similar to `combineAll()` that emits as soon as any of the source observables emits for the first time? If not, what's the clearest way of doing it?

What I've tried:

```js
const source1$ = service.getSomeData();
const source2$ = service.getOtherData();

combineLatest(
  source1$,
  source2$
).pipe(
  map([source1Data, source2Data] => {
    // this code only gets executed when both observables emits for the first time
    return source1Data + source2Data;
  })
)
```

Comment: Your example indicates you need both values to perform the operation. What are you going to do with only 1 value (the first to be emitted)?

Comment: Yes, I need both values to perform the operation. But, until I have both values, the value combineLatest emits is `null`. What I want is emit the starting value of the first observable (empty array for example) until the second one arrives. Then, I can perform the operation and return another list based on the second observable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. `combineLatest` does not emit anything before all input observables have emitted at least once. If you want to receive a compound value immediately regardless of input state - e.g. `[null, 'source2Data']` - there is no other way than to explicitly push that initial `null` value through each input observable.

Comment: My guess is that you need withLatestFrom instead of combineLatest. This way you can have one observable that determines when something should happen and withLatestFrom will just give you the last emitted value of some other observables. You can pass multiple observables into withLatestFrom, and it will give you an array of values -> one value for each observable. You might still need startWith though.

Comment: "Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value. This is the same behavior as withLatestFrom and can be a gotcha as there will be no output and no error but one (or more) of your inner observables is likely not functioning as intended, or a subscription is late." - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One way is prefixing all sources with `startWith`:

```
combineLatest([
  source1$.pipe(startWith(?)),
  source2$.pipe(startWith(?)),
])
```

> that emits as soon as any of the source observables emits for the first time?

This looks like you might be looking for `race(source1$, source2$)` Observable creation method or maybe just `merge(source1$, source2$).pipe(take(1))`. But it really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is for example, returning `source1Data + source2Data`, so I need each source data in the `map()` callback (so only `merge()` or `race()` are not suitable). I had not thought about using `startWith()` operator, but as data comes from the app state (ngrx store) I prefer not to "guess" it's first value.

Comment: @EliasGarcia So which one you want? Emit only when all source Observables emit or emit when at least one source emits?

Comment: I need to emit the value of the first observable until the second one arrives. When the second one arrives, I need to do some calcs and return a combined results based on both observable inputs.

Comment: So maybe something like this `concat(source1$.pipe(take(1)), combineLatest(source1$, source2$))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! No filters, maps, the cleanest way of doing it for sure, thanks a lot!

Comment: @martin Regarding the `concat ` example, what happens if `source2$` emits first? Its value will never be delivered 'standalone' if so, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true. But if you replace `concat` with `merge` it will subscribe to `combineLatest` right away and then even if `source2$` emits first it won't be forgotten.

Comment: Isuppose that would still not work, since the only input observable that will actually ever emit data from source 2 _is_ the result of combineLatest, which will not emit until also source 1 emits. The problem remains in this case.

Comment: And after this, `pipe( skip(1) )` can be useful to ignore the first mock value[s]

Answer (score 80):

If I understand correctly you want a pattern like the following diagram:

```
stream1$ => ------ 1 ------ 12 -----------------------
stream2$ => ------------------------- 30 -------------
            
result$  => ------ 1 ------ 12 ------ 42 --------------
```

If one value is available, emit that. If both are available, emit the combination of both, a simple sum in this case (12 + 30 = 42);

First the input streams, I've made them subjects for the sake of this example, so we can push data in manually:

```
const stream1$ = new Subject();
const stream2$ = new Subject();
```

Next we'll combine the inputs, first piped through the startWith operator. This makes sure that combineLatest produces an observable that emits immediately - `[null, null]` to be precise.

```
const combined$ = combineLatest([
  stream1$.pipe(startWith(null)),
  stream2$.pipe(startWith(null)),
]);
```

Now you have an observable that always emits arrays of length 2, containing any combination of your data (numbers in this example) and null, like the following diagram:

```
stream1$ | startWith(NULL) => NULL ----------- 1 ----------- 12 ----------------------------
stream2$ | startWith(NULL) => NULL ---------------------------------------- 30 -------------

combined$                     [NULL, NULL] --- [1, NULL] --- [12, NULL] --- [12, 30] -------
```

Finally you can inspect and `map` this output to your desired format: the sum of 2 numbers if both are available, or the first value to be available:

```
const processedCombinations$ = combined$.pipe(
  map(([data1, data2]) => {
    if (data1 === null) return data2;
    if (data2 === null) return data1;
    
    return data1 + data2;
  }),
);
```

Result:

```
combined$                  => [NULL, NULL] --- [1, NULL] --- [12, NULL] --- [12, 30] -------
processedCombinations$     => NULL ----------- 1 ----------- 12 ----------- 42 -------------
```

One problem remains: the first value emitted from `combined$` is `[null, null]`, causing `processedCombinations$` to emit `null` initially. One way to fix this is to chain another pipe using `skipWhile` onto `processedCombinations$`:

```
const final$ = processedCombinations$.pipe(skipWhile((input) => input === null));
```

Result:

```
combined$                  => [NULL, NULL] --- [1, NULL] --- [12, NULL] --- [12, 30] -------
processedCombinations$     => NULL ----------- 1 ----------- 12 ----------- 42 -------------
final$                     => ---------------- 1 ----------- 12 ----------- 42 -------------
```

Another - imo better - way is to filter the `combined$` stream before `processedCombinations$` (now actually `final$`) is created from it:

```
const combinedFiltered$ = combined$.pipe(
    filter(([first, second])=> first !== null || second !== null),
);

const final$ = combinedFiltered$.pipe(
    map(([data1, data2]) => {
        if (data1 === null) return data2;
        if (data2 === null) return data1;

        return data1 + data2;
    }),
);
```

A corresponding diagram shows nicely how irrelevant values are eliminated as early in the stream hierarchy as possible:

```
combined$                  => [NULL, NULL] --- [1, NULL] --- [12, NULL] --- [12, 30] -------
combinedFiltered$          => ---------------- [1, NULL] --- [12, NULL] --- [12, 30] -------
final$                     => ---------------- 1 ----------- 12 ----------- 42 -------------
```

The above diagrams can be produced with this code:

```
final$.subscribe(console.log);

stream1$.next(1);
// logs: 1

stream1$.next(12);
// logs: 12

stream2$.next(30);
// logs: 42
```

*Imports used:*

```js
import { combineLatest, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, skipWhile, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: SUCH a good answer, thoughtful, helpful diagrams, love it! I ended up using `combineLatest` (but `startWith(null)` only on the `2nd` which doesn't fire immediately) then `.pipe` then `map()` where `if (2nd === null) return 1st`... Granted, it isn't as nice/correct as yours but it's short and works nice for my situation :) Thanks again!

Comment: I did not get a point, which is combineLatest should actually wait for both the source to emit one value at least(Refered from the document), I have created a simple example here(https://playcode.io/1659950), can you please help me understand how is it working? In it, how come the value from first source is emitted even if there is a delay of 1 sec.