# RxJS - Combine multiple observables and emit any value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I know how to combine observables and fetch the result when all observables emit at least one value (combineLatest, forkJoin, etc.).

But how can I emit a value when one of many observables emits a value?

For example:

```
const adModelChangedObs$ = this.editAdService.adModelChanged; // Angular subject one
const refreshPreviewClickedObs$ = this.editAdService.refreshPreviewClick // Angular subject two

merge([adModelChangedObs$, refrshPreviewClickedObs$]).subscribe(() => {
     console.log('One of the two observables emitted a value');
});
```

The subscribe handler is not being executed, although I tried it with many RxJS operators for far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJS combineLatest without waiting for source observables to emit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039425/rxjs-combinelatest-without-waiting-for-source-observables-to-emit)

Comment: Can you make sure by subscribing separately to the above `adModel` and `refreshPreview` that they are emitting?

Comment: You can use combineLatest. combineLatest starts emitting after one of the observable emits. forkJoin waits all to emit at least once.

Comment: merge should work, but you have to give it observables, not an array.

Comment: Sorry but none of your advices did the trick. I have to use "startsWith" to initialize the observables. Otherwise, it does not work.

Comment: @enne87 Can you post your solution using `startWith` that did work? It might be helpful to others.

Comment: @StvnBrkdll It also works with the merge approach mentioned in the comment below.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, the [merge](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) function should help in your case, however, you have to pass the observables as args, not as an array.

You can try it like the following:

```js
// import { merge } from 'rxjs';

const adModelChangedObs$ = this.editAdService.adModelChanged; // Angular subject one
const refreshPreviewClickedObs$ = this.editAdService.refreshPreviewClick; // Angular subject two

merge(adModelChangedObs$, refrshPreviewClickedObs$).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('One of the two observables emitted a value');
});
```

However, if that's not working, then you need to make sure that your `editAdService` observables emit the value correctly.

Comment: I'll re-check it. Thank you very much!